# Merge associative, multidimensional array php

Tags: php, multidimensional-array, merge, associative-array

I have a little Problem with a 2-dimensional and associative array which i need to merge in PHP.

So what i'm trying to achieve as output is something like this:

```
Array ( [0] => 6 [1] => 5 [2] => 9 [3] => 8 [4] => 3 [5] => 16 [6] => 55 
        [7] => 59 [8] => 56 [9] => 3 [10] => 4 .... [1293] => 2)
```

At the moment my output is as follows:

```
foreach ($arrayList as $key  => $list) {
                        print_r($list);
                    }
```

is

```
Array ( [hgeneral1] => 6 [hgeneral2] => 5 [hgeneral3] => 9 [hgeneral4] => 8 
[hgeneral5] => 3 [hgeneral6] => 16 [hmusic1] => 55 [hmusic2] => 59 [hmusic3] => 56 )
Array ( [hgeneral1] => 3 [hgeneral2] => 4 [hgeneral3] => 8 [hgeneral4] => 10 [hgeneral5]
=> 16 [hgeneral6] => 17 [hsport1] => 26 [hsport2] => 32 [hsport3] => 35 [hsport4] => 38
[hsport5] => 41 [hsport6] => 42 [hmusic1] => 55 [hmusic2] => 56 [hmusic3] => 58
[hmusic4] => 60 [hmusic5] => 61 ) Array ....
```

and like 50 more arrays.

Now since it's a associative array merge will just overwrite the values (if i understood that right), so my question is: Is there a way to get all these values into one big array?

I would really appreciate any help and sorry for my bad english (and the maybe kinda noobish question, but i'm really new to programming).

Cheers

Jutschge

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"If the arrays contain numeric keys, the later value will not overwrite the original value, but will be appended." [array_merge doc](http://php.net/manual/ro/function.array-merge.php)

So take the values with array_values first and then merge like array_merge(array_values(arr1),array_values(arr2) .. )